# Init date with asynchronous API call and vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, vuex

I try to understand how to init data from async API call and display child component.
I use computed properties to share data between parent & child Component.
I use store, action for API call, and mutation to update data.

Problem, asynchronous API call end after that my child component was mounted, what is the good practice to fix that ?

My parent component `App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <expensesChart :groupedExpenses="groupedExpenses" />
</template>

<script>
    import expensesChart from './components/expensesChart.vue'
    import main from './assets/js/main.js';

    export default {
    components: {
        expensesChart,
    },
    mounted() {
        main.init();
        this.$store.dispatch('loadExpenses');
    },
  
    computed: {
        groupedExpenses() {
            return this.$store.state.groupedExpenses; 
        },
        error() {
            return this.$store.state.error;
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

My child component `expensesChart.vue`:

```
<template>
        <div class="container">  
            <div class=" overflow-hidden">
                <canvas class="" id="chartLine"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>  
</template>

<script>
import { Chart, registerables} from 'chart.js';
import myChart from '../assets/js/chart.js';

export default {
    name: 'expensesChart',
    //propriété de donnée du parent, passage en attribut html
    props: ['groupedExpenses'],
    created() {
        //console.log('CREATED CHART');
        Chart.register(...registerables);
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('mounted');
        //this.$props.groupedExpenses is empty because of the synchronous shift
        console.log(this.$props.groupedExpenses);
        const data = myChart.loadDataChart(this.$props.groupedExpenses, 'week');
        const configLineChart = myChart.setConfChart(data)
        //create chart
        const myLineChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('chartLine'),configLineChart);
        //init chart 
        myChart.init(myLineChart);
    },
}
</script>
```

My store :

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000';

export default createStore( {
    state: {
        groupedExpenses: [],
        error: '',
    },
    mutations: {
        loadExpenses(state, groupedExpenses) {
            console.log(' up state expenses');
            state.groupedExpenses = groupedExpenses;
            console.log(state.groupedExpenses);
        },
        updateError(state, error) {
            state.error = error;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        //load finances infos
        async loadExpenses({ commit }, period = 'week') {
            try {
                const financeList = await axios.get(`/finance/${period}`);
                if (!financeList.data) {
                    commit('updateError','Impossible de récupérer les dépenses');
                }
                if (!financeList.data.length) {
                    commit('updateError','Aucune dépenses');
                }
                else {
                    commit('loadExpenses', financeList.data);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                commit('updateError', error);
            }
        },
        setError({ commit }, error) {
            commit('updateError', error);
        }
    },

});
```

Comment: The solution is to not init the app or not render the child until data in the store is ready. For other scenarios it may be different, but here it's simple as that.

Comment: I'm ok this that, but how to do that with the store ? (I'm a beginner with Vuejs)Maybe Vue 3 js with Suspence can be a solution ?

Comment: You need to complete store actions before rendering a child, e.g. `await store.dispatch('loadExpenses'); app.mount(...)`. The question doesn't mention that suspense is available (it's not in Vue 2), but yes, it serves this purpose, basically expensesChart  needs to be asynchronous component, and its parent needs to use it with <suspense>